# How to export JMeter results to JSON?

Tags: json, jmeter

We run load tests with JMeter and would like to export result data (throughput, latency, requests per second etc.) to JSON, either a file or STDOUT. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter can save the results in a CSV format with header.

(Do not forget to select Save Field Names - it is OFF by default)

[image]

Then you can use this tool to covert the CSV to a JSON.

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

[image]

**EDIT**

JMeter stores the result in XML or CSV format. XML is by default (with .jtl extension). But It is always recommended to save the result in csv format.

If you want to convert XML to JSON

http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.U9O2ifldVBk

If you are planning to use CSV, To save the result in CSV format automatically

When you are running your test via command line, to save the result in csv for a specific test

```
%JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat" -n -t %TESTNAME% -p %PROPERTY_FILE_PATH% -l %RESULT_FILE_PATH% -j %LOG_FILE_PATH% -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

Or

You can update the jmeter.properties in bin folder to enable below property (for any test you run)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

Hope, it is clear!

Comment: Thanks, @vIns! Do you know, if it's possible to automatically export result data to CSV format? Or this shoud be done manually after each run?

Comment: @weekens, Please check the EDIT section of this answer.

Comment: Ok, @vIns, we'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB solution for this but you could inspire yourself from this patch:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53668